# How to free memory used by tkinter widgets

Tags: python, model-view-controller, user-interface, tkinter

I have a single-window tkinter application that reads data stored in a separate python class to update the values in the interface, and vice versa. I have somewhat merged the View and Controller of the traditional MVC structure. The GUI is drawn by iterating through a dict that describes the widget type, its XY location in the grid and a few other parameters.

When the user selects an option from one of the OptionMenus or enters values into the Entry widgets, the "command" attributes are used to update the values stored in the Model class. When the user clicks an "Apply" button, the Model is converted to JSON and sent via HTTP to configure a separate piece of hardware.

There are two "banks" of data, both of which have the same parameters, but they can be configured differently. To handle this, there is a Button which will refresh the display to show the values from the other bank. The GUI is also refreshed when the current values on the remote hardware are updated.

The current way I have achieved this is to create a Frame within the main window, and put all the widgets within this. When the GUI needs refreshing, I loop through removing all of the children of the main Frame:

```
for child in self.mainFrame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_forget()
    child.destroy()
    del child
```

and then I remove the Frame itself:

```
self.mainFrame.grid_forget()
self.mainFrame.destroy()
del self.mainFrame
```

this is all done within a method of the GUI class that is called when the Button is clicked. The `self.drawGUI()` method is then called which reads the data from the model again and draws all new widgets in a new Frame.

The issue I am having is that every time I click the "Refresh" button and run this method, the memory usage increases by around 500KB, as if the old widgets aren't being deleted. I have tried `gc.collect()` at various points in the loop but with no luck. Am I dereferencing the widgets correctly? How come they aren't going away?

**Additional Info**: When I am creating the widgets they are not being assigned to a variable, so i call the function like this:

```
Tk.Button(...)
```

rather than

```
button = Tk.Button(...)
```

I'm not sure if this will make any difference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I have somewhat merged the View and Controller of the traditional MVC structure."* .. emm .. are you trying to reimplement rails for python? I thought Django already had done it.

Comment: I'm not making a web application or a framework, it is a regular desktop app. I have just made the view include methods to update the model directly, rather than using a separate controller process.